# How to declare multiple where condition for a table

Tags: php

hi guy's i have a question.
how to declare a multiple where clause condition inside one php only.
i have try to make my project has a minimum of a php file. i want to make my where clause inside one php file only.

this is the problem i mean. i want to put my code into one php file or inside one `<?php` `?>`. the php code like this

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$date1= $_POST['date1'];
// Data for Titik1
$sql = "SELECT * FROM termocouple where tanggal='$date1' AND silo='Silo 1'";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

on the code above the query has select table `termocouple` and the filter of where condition is `tanggal` and `silo`. now the problem is i have 12 php file like that. and the different of every php is from the selecting `silo`, i put `Silo 1`,`Silo 2`,`Silo 3`, ....`Silo 12`.

please someone help me with this. i want to make it simple in one php file. im really appreciated when you give me an example

Comment: Meaning you want a single php file that will handle
silo='Silo 1'
silo='Silo 2'
silo='Silo 3'
..
silo='Silo 12'
Which means you want a reusable code. Is that it?

Comment: yeah like that. 
i want to make that 12 php file with same query but different selecting of `silo` id's  in one php file,

Comment: Then why not just pass 'silo' as POST too? Same as date1?
and make 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM termocouple where tanggal='$date1' AND silo='$silo";

Comment: @keysl i mean like this. on one single php. i want to make a selecting use this query `$sql = "SELECT * FROM termocouple where tanggal='$date1' AND silo='Silo 1'";` but has different of the value of the id's `silo`. the id's `silo` with value `silo='Silo 1'` , `silo='Silo 2'`.....`silo='Silo 12'`

Comment: You know, your code is highly prone to sql injectios?

Comment: @Philipp from `$_POST` right?

Comment: @RobSutan not especially `$_POST` - each var you pass to mysql could be potential dangerous and you should escape each of them (i.e. use prepared statements)

Comment: @Philipp yeah bro. i know that. this code just a fast code. im not really care about the security right now. i just want to know how to make something like my comment bellow on Jaydeep answer

Comment: @RobSutan I would suggest to move the whole thing into an function with the params `silo` and `date` - would make much more sense

Answer (score 1):

In order to minimize your code, if you are using the same query or `code` more than one time in the same project, it is more recommended to create a function, that you will call anytime you need to execute the code.

So here, since you are using the same query 12 times, you will have to create a function that executes this query, and then call this function every time you want to execute the query.

The function takes parameters, so you will have to give the function the database connection parameter `$db` in order to connect to the database since you are using this connection inside the function, and then you have to add the values of the where clause to the parameters also.

So your function here will take the database connection `$db`, `$date1` fetched from `$_POST`, and `$silo` fetched from `$_POST`

At the end of the function, you can return any value you wish to return, so in your case, you will have to return the `$rows` array fetched from the query

Create a common `php file`and create a function in it.
Lets say the file name is `libraries.php`

in this file write the following code:

```
<?php
    function getRows($db, $date, $silo) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM termocouple where tanggal='$date' AND silo='$silo'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $rows = array();

        while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $rows[] = $tmp;
        }

        return json_encode($rows);
    }
?>
```

And in each of the files where you are calling the query you will remove the php code and replace it with the following:

```
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");
include("{path-to-file}/libraries.php");

$date1= $_POST['date1'];
$silo = $_POST['silo'];

$rows = getRows($db, $date1, $silo) ;
?>
```

Comment: can you explain to me Mario?

Comment: the function of  `$rows=getRows($db,$date1,$silo);`

Comment: i think i get your answer. it still need the client side put a variable into `$silo` right?

Comment: You can put it static in each page `$silo = 'silo 1'`, or you can get it from the `$_POST` request. It is up to you

Comment: maybe i didn't get the right conclusion from your answer. when i use static in each page i'm still make more code like the 2nd code of yours ?

Comment: Create a function, and call it in all the pages that you want to use the query, but the variable `$silo`, it can be given to the function parameters as a static value, or as a dynamic value. But it is more recommended to be fetched from `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming these 12 PHPs are called in diff scenarios. Why dont you pass some param from client side so that the PHP knows which scenario to execute.

```
$date1= $_POST['date1'];
$silo= $_POST['silo'];//This could be 'Silo 1 OR 'Silo 2' etc.
// Data for Titik1
$sql = "SELECT * FROM termocouple where tanggal='$date1' AND silo='$silo'";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
```

Comment: This is what I'll recommend too. Just add a bit of security using  mysql_real_escape_string and it'll good to go.

Comment: @keysl `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated and not available in php 7 - prepared statements are the way to go

Comment: @Jaydeep Rajput when use client side like that i've done right now. the condition is like this. i want to show a data from `Silo 1 - Silo 12` but it will showing in different table and every table just contain data of  silo 

ex: at date 23.10.2017 has data from silo 1-7 then it will showing 7 table contain every data from every silo from 1-7

Comment: @Philipp that code just a fast code that i made. i try it 1st then i will change for the security